# Algebra and calculus's books for master

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I want to prepare myself for entrance master exam for one of the universities in America, I will be grateful if you tell me which books are good to study *linear algebra* and *calculus*?
Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804716/very-good-linear-algebra-book?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186450/what-is-the-best-calculus-book-for-my-case, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600315/book-for-studying-calculus-i

Comment: RIGHT PLACE FOR THIS QUESTION. ?. OFF TOPIC ?. Book recomendations? Is this what this site is for (don't ask me). For advanced things like Q-analysis - absolutely (my friend is a researcher in Q-analysis).

Comment: I mean, I want to pursue my major in impa or Cinvesta and these institute take an exam like entrance exam.

Comment: If you already know some calculus, I would recommend you study with *Mathematical Analysis* by Apostol and either *Linear Algebra* by Lang or *Algebra* by Artin. If you don't know calculus well, you can use *Calculus* by Apostol. This book also contains some material on linear algebra.

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot. I will study these books that you recommended. I wish best things of God for you. In my view you are one of good person in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intro to linear algebra by Dave Lay is popular for beginners.Calculus 10th edition by James Stewart is well known.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I studied Linear Algebra by Hoffman Kenneth, Kunze Ray is this book enough?

Comment: Its a good book.